# PostgreSQL: Add cities to points by ST_Contains()

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a table with 2 columns:

```
-geom : (Lat/lang pairs in this from) ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longg,lat),4326)

-city : an empty column
```

I have an imported shape file from a country(as a table with polygons), and i would like to add each geom point an exact city in to the city column with `ST_Contains()`.

For each geom point, check every city polygon and if it is an inside point add the city name to the city column.

**Q:** How can i make this structure(the nested for cycle)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normal `UPDATE FROM` should work.
Assuming the tables `shp` contains columns city_geom and city_name.

```
UPDATE tbl
SET city=s.city_name
FROM shp AS s
WHERE
ST_CONTAINS(s.city_geom,geom);
```